# Number of possible integers less than 100000 such that the digits 4,5,6 appear in that order

Tags: combinatorics

I have been stuck on this problem for some time and I am not sure how to approach it:
"How many positive integers less than 100,000 have digits containing 4,5,6 in that particular order?" (by this it means that the digits "456" must appear one after another in the number)

I am thinking that I would multiply 10X10X3X2X1 since the two of the five digit spaces can hold any digit between 0-9 and the other 3 must have 456 however I do not think this considers the order of the digits or the fact that the smallest possible integer would be 456. (if that makes any sense)

How would I modify this so that the order of the numbers matter?
What would the answer be to this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: One important thing to take from the answers is the importance of clearly asking the question.  The answers are different because they are answering different questions, all of which are reasonable readings of what is posted.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is the wording that my teacher used. They assumed that we understood that the question was asking for "456" in the number. I will update the post (since they confirmed this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a total of $5$ digits

The $3$ digit block $4,5,6$ can be placed in $3$ positions. ($1,2,3$ and $2,3,4$ and $3,4,5$)

$3×10×10$

So there are a total of $300$ numbers in which the digits $4,5,6$ appear in this order consecutively

Comment: Err...what?${}$

Comment: Wdym?, We take 4 5 6 as a single block, Now this 3 digit block has 3 ways to be placed, taking up positions $1,2,3$ or $2,3,4$ or $3,4,5$, so there are 3 ways to position this block, moreover, there are $10^2$ ways to choose the remaining 2 digits

Comment: The problem does not say that $4$, $5$, and $6$ appear consecutively.

Comment: I interpreted it wrong then, I think it wasnt clear in the Question if I had to make them a block or not

Comment: Your comment is much easier to understand than "4 can be on 3 positions"! Perhaps you could edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Sure, I will edit it right now

Comment: I think you should explicitly state in your answer that you are counting those arrangements in which the digits $4$, $5$, $6$ appear consecutively in that order.

Comment: Update: my teacher accepted this as the correct answer! They used the same reasoning as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the problem statement, I will think that digits $4,5,6$ appear only once, do not need to be consecutive digits, and the sequence is always $4$ first and $6$ last.

From $5$ digits, we choose $3$ to put $4,5,6$ in that order. $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.

The remaining $2$ digits can be anything but $4,5,6$. $7^{2}$ ways.

So there are $\binom{5}{3}7^{2}$ possible integers

Comment: I just started this class in high school yesterday so I am not really sure what the 5 over the three means, do you mind explaining this?

Comment: $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5\times 4 \times 3}{3 \times 2 \times 1}$. It means choosing $3$ objects from $5$ objects and the order of choosing is not important. We use this here since we want to choose $3$ digits from $5$ digits and the order is not important since $4$ will always go to the first digit of the $3$ and $6$ goes to the last of the $3$.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if the order did matter, what would I do?

Comment: @NicoleK then multiply it by number of permutation of $3$ objects, which is $3!$ to get $5\times 4\times 3$.

Answer (score 0):

We can represent any nonnegative integer less than $100000$ as a five-digit string by appending leading zeros as necessary.  For instance, we can represent $456$ as $00456$ and $4956$ as $04956$.

There are ten possible positions in which the first $4$, first $5$, and first $6$ could appear:

$456\square\square$

$45\square 6 \square$

$45 \square \square 6$

$4 \square 56 \square$

$4 \square 5 \square 6$

$4 \square \square 56$

$\square 456 \square$

$\square 45 \square 6$

$\square 4 \square 56$

$\square \square 456$

Any position before the first $4$ can be filled in $7$ ways since it cannot be a $4$, $5$, or $6$.

Any position after the first $4$ but before the first $5$ can be filled in $8$ ways since it cannot be a $5$ or $6$.

Any position after the first $5$ but before the first $6$ can be filled in $9$ ways since it cannot be a $6$.

Any position after the first $6$ can be filled in $10$ ways.

Thus, the number of nonnegative integers less than $100000$ in which the digits $4$, $5$, and $6$ appear in that order is 
$$1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 + 7 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 + 7 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 1 + 7 \cdot 1 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 + 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$$

If you make the assumption that the digits $4$, $5$, and $6$ each appear *exactly* once, you obtain Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's answer.  This is because there would be only seven choices for each of the other two positions.

Comment: "Any position after the first 4 but before the first 5 can be filled in 8 ways since it cannot be a 5 or 6."  I don't see why it can't be a 6.  For example $14656$ should be counted (I think); but there is a $6$ between the first 4 and the 5.

Comment: @paw88789  The problem states that the digits $4$, $5$, and $6$ appear in that order, so the first $4$ appears before the first $5$ and the first $5$ appears before the first $6$.

Comment: @paw88789 In particular, in your example $14656$, the digits first appear in the order $465$ rather than $456$.

Comment: I would say the statement is open to interpretation, as to whether, for instance, 14656 is admissible or not.